# Youtube data api with type video also returns channel

Tags: youtube-data-api

Youtube data api is mistakenly returning one channel even if the "type=video" is set.

For example, the query "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=coldplay&type=video&key=API_KEY&part=snippet&maxResults=10&fields=items(snippet/title,id/videoId)" returns the following result :

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "id": {
    "videoId": "YykjpeuMNEk"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Coldplay - Hymn For The Weekend (Official Video)"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "videoId": "z9BPMjL44Aw"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Coldplay & Big Sean - Miracles (Someone Special) - Official Lyric Video"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "videoId": "FM7MFYoylVs"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "The Chainsmokers & Coldplay - Something Just Like This (Lyric)"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "videoId": "KnLNG0WnGsI"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Coldplay - All I Can Think About Is You (Official Lyric Video)"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "videoId": "we-LaiQNY5s"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Coldplay - A L I E N S (Official Lyric Video)"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "videoId": "WXmTEyq5nXc"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Coldplay - Hypnotised (Official Lyric Video)"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "videoId": "BPNTC7uZYrI"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Coldplay - Up&Up (Official Video)"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "videoId": "VPRjCeoBqrI"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Coldplay - A Sky Full Of Stars (Official Video)"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "videoId": "QtXby3twMmI"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Coldplay - Adventure Of A Lifetime (Official Video)"
   }
  },
  {
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Coldplay Official"
   }
  },
 ]
}
```

The last result here for a channel and has no "videoId".

Why is this problem occurring ? Is anything wrong with my query URL ?

Comment: I just removed the empty ones :/ . The other problem is that the next pages results are inconsistent.

Comment: It's 2019 now and yet this bug still exists